# how to run maas when network can't be connected

Tags: maas

I am using maas to manage my bare metal
I found that when adding HOST to maas or through maas deploy host, maas or host must be able to connect to the Internet, otherwise the whole process will fail

Does anyone have experience in this area?

I have used the offline import method to add the image to Maas.